# Error:(137, 57) error: incompatible types: fragmentAboutUs cannot be converted to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have to use `Fragments` in my app, so I have whose moments, but one of those fragments will contain another fragment, that i need for `ViewPager`. I found many articles with guides and it was almost done, but i have to transform one of my fragments into `FragmentActivity`, thats why i cant use it as normal `Fragment`. how to create such tree, where I will have 4 fragments and one of them will be a parrent for another one.

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        if (id == R.id.nav_new_order)
        {
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fNewOrder);
        }
        else if (id == R.id.nav_orders)
        {
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fOrders);
        }
        else if (id == R.id.nav_settlements)
        {
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fSettlements);
        }
        else if (id == R.id.nav_about_us)
        {
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fAboutUs);
        }
        else if (id == R.id.nav_exit)
        {
            // exit

            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            intent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        assert drawer != null;
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

And here I have that my "baby", I have to use in one of my fragments. It's implemented already, it works, but I cannot call it because of that problem I have: parrent is not `Fragment` anymore

```
    public class fragmentAboutUs extends FragmentActivity
{
    static final String TAG = "myLogs";
    static final int PAGE_COUNT = 4;

    ViewPager pager;
    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_about_us_pages);

        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pagerAdapter = new fragmentAboutUs.MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "onPageSelected, position = " + position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
                                       int positionOffsetPixels)
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state)
            {
            }
        });
    }

    private class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
    {
        private MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
        {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            return AboutUsPages.newInstance(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return PAGE_COUNT;
        }

    }
}
```

So what should I do, how to use my parrent as fragment, but implement child as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your import

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

to

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

Comment: i'm already using that import, that's about my class implement. I dont know, how to run it, my fragment should extend Fragment to work normaly, but if i want to use my child correcty, i have to use Fragment Activity =\